# Can you make all natural number from 3?

Tags: natural-numbers

Can you make all natural number from 3 with only four function that

## $$x!,\; \sqrt{x},\;\lceil x\rceil,\;\lfloor x \rfloor $$

?

ex)
$1=\lfloor \sqrt3 \rfloor$

$\;\;\;\;\;2= \lceil \sqrt3 \rceil$

$\;\;\;\;\;3=3$

$\;\;\;\;\;4=\lceil\left(\sqrt{3!}\right)!\rceil$

$\;\;\;\;\;5=\lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt{(3!)!}} \rfloor$

---

I know that all natural number s.t. $n \geq 3$ can make 3.

Comment: My knowledge here is extremely limited, but could there be a proof by induction?

Comment: Apparently, we are allowed to use $\Gamma(x+1)$ instead of $x!$ as the example for $4$ shows.

Comment: Just note that you can often hit two consecutive numbers by changing floor/ceiling functions at the end, for example $(8,9) = (\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\rfloor, \lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\rceil)$, $(10,11)=(\lfloor\sqrt{5!}\rfloor, \lceil\sqrt{5!}\rceil)$, $(14,15)=(\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{8!}}\rfloor, \lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{8!}}\rceil)$.